# Best way to authorize gateway access to IAM and Cognito using CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk

Using CDK, I have a gateway rest api lambda which I want to be accessible to;

- Members of a cognito user pool
- Other lambdas in my stack

As far as I know there is no way to add 2 authorizers to the same gateway resource method?

So this means I have 2 options;

1. Create custom [Lambda authoriser](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-use-lambda-authorizer.html) which verifies tokens for cognito and IAM
2. Add 2 separate recourses to my api and call a different endpoint from my client vs my lambdas. E.g:

`/external/route1` with [cognito authorizer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/solutions/latest/constructs/aws-cognito-apigateway-lambda.html)

`/internal/route1` with iam authorizer

Which of these approaches is better? I imagine option 2 is easier to setup. Are there any CDK examples or constructs that could help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can run Cognito authorizers down the whole stack and then check the scopes per internal service. At a gateway, Cognito authorizers will validate the token and check the scopes against what you've specified. I don't know about CDK, but if you're using Pulumi Crosswalk, it's really trivial to setup Cognito Authorizers in APIGW, something like this:

```js
const api = new awsx.apigateway.API(<NAME>, {
  routes: [{
    path: <PATH>,
    method: <METHOD>,
    eventHandler: <LAMBDA>,
    authorizers: [awsx.apigateway.getCognitoAuthorizer({
        providerARNs: [<USERPOOL>],
        methodsToAuthorize: ['<RESOURCE>/<SCOPE>']
    })]
  }]
});
```